# Webpack not inserting vue build

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm building a small app using Vue, Typescript, and Electron. I used the Vue CLI to start the project and installed the electron builder plugin. Everything worked.

However, I like my electron apps to have a specific file structure, so I moved my files and adjusted my configs to get what I wanted. Once I got it to build, the Vue app doesn't show up, either in Electron or on the web. When I inspect the page, there is nothing there except for the base `index.html`. I'm not getting any errors, either in the terminal or in dev tools.

Here is my vue.config.js

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  pages: {
    app: {
      entry: './src/renderer/index.ts'
    }
  },
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      mainProcessFile: 'src/main/index.ts'
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: config => {
    // console.log(config.entry)
    // console.log(config.resolve.alias)
    config.resolve = {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        '@': (path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/renderer'))
      }
    }
    // console.log(config.resolve)
  }
}
```

What do I need to do to get my Vue app to build/show up?